# Virtually flustered with virtual ints

Tags: c++

Im confused what virtual int and virtual string means.

Moreover, I'm confused what the prefix "virtual" has to do with anything; I have a feeling it has to do with vectors.

Comment: `virtual` in C++ normally refers to member functions, and their ability that they are dispatched to the most derived type when invoked on a reference to a base class.

Comment: have you read a [book about C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: Please show the code that caused your confusion: there are two places where `virtual` can be used in C++, and they are very different.

Comment: Unless you have worked with inheritance, you really don't need to know anything about virtual. You can get to that when you get there, until then, don't even bother trying with it.

Comment: I understand what it means now, thank you Xeo.  If you make your comment an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Not if there's an `int` after it and the OP isn't getting a compiler error. There's only one place where virtual could be used like that.

Comment: alexy, @Xeo isn't guaranteed to see your reply to his comment unless you prefix his name with @.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I forgot about it.  I'll make a new comment since I can't edit my last one.  @Xeo

Comment: Don't worry about that. :) Just accept another answer, @Omnifarious' in particular looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `virtual` has nothing to do with the `int`, nor does it have anything to do with vectors. The `int` specifies the type of value the function returns when it's done. The `virtual` specifies that the function call be handled in a special way that's related to inheritance.

I expect this question has duplicate answers on here already. Search for stuff about the `virtual` keyword in C++.

Your question is a very elementary C++ question, and I believe a full explanation of what `virtual` means is outside the scope of what StackOverflow can help you with anyway. You should find a nice beginners C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

`virtual` describes a **class member function** in most cases.

If you see `virtual int some_function()` it's the *function* that's virtual.

You can learn about the concept [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).

Answer (score 0):

In C++ "virtual" is a keyword used in a class' or struct's method declarations that makes the function polymorphic based on the object type. You can read up on the basic, language-independent concept at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function, but you'd be best served reading an introduction C++ book to learn how this is used.